# Configure OpenIdConnect Owin middleware to fire only once

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webforms, openid-connect

I have an asp.net 4.8 web application, it is hybrid webforms/mvc. I am moving it from forms authentication to OpenIdconnect authentication using Owin.

I have a Startup.cs class with the usual "Use" calls in the Configuration() method. First is this call:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType,
        });
```

And then the call to my identity provider:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {...[identity provider code here]}
```

All of this works fine. I have some code I need to run after the user is authenticated, so I added a custom Owin middleware class that I call right after the above call to app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() inside the Startup.cs Configuration() method. It looks like this:

```
app.UseAfterAuthentication();
```

This works fine as well. The method signature looks like this:

```
        public static void UseAfterAuthentication(this IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {[code here}
```

My problem is, app.UseAfterAuthentication() fires after every request. There is no need for this. I only need this method to run once, immediately after the user is authenticated.

As far as I can tell, it appears that  app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication only fires once (there is no indication if fires from verbose logging, and none of the functions it invokes are fired). I'd like my custom method to behave in the same way.

I set a cookie after the initial invocation of app.UseAfterAuthentication(), and at the top of the method I check for the existence of this cookie and bail out when it exists. But I would rather that this method not fire at all after the first time.

Is there anything I can change so that the method app.UseAfterAuthentication() only fires once?

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core has the method app.UseWhen() on its IApplicationBuilder class. The answer is to create an extension method that does the same thing in .Net Framework.

Here is the extension method, ported from .Net Core to .Net Framework 4.8, I stole the code below from this github link: `https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/147`

```
using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;
using Predicate = Func<IOwinContext, bool>;

public static class UseWhenExtensions
{
    public static IAppBuilder UseWhen(this IAppBuilder app, Predicate predicate, Action<IAppBuilder> configuration)
    {
        if (app == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(app));
        }

        if (predicate == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
        }

        if (configuration == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
        }

        // Create and configure the branch builder right away; otherwise,
        // we would end up running our branch after all the components
        // that were subsequently added to the main builder.
        var branchBuilder = app.New();
        configuration(branchBuilder);

        return app.Use(new Func<AppFunc, AppFunc>(main =>
        {
            // This is called only when the main application builder 
            // is built, not per request.
            branchBuilder.Run(context => main(context.Environment));
            var branch = (AppFunc)branchBuilder.Build(typeof(AppFunc));

            return context =>
            {
                if (predicate(new OwinContext(context)))
                {
                    return branch(context);
                }
                else
                {
                    return main(context);
                }
            };
        }));
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it in my Startup class, right after my call to app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication. Note that the call to the UseAfterAuthentication() extension method is made on "appBuilder", not on "app." If you use the latter it will still fire on every request, and you will wonder "why did I waste all of that time?"

```
app.UseWhen(context => context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && context.Request.Cookies["AddedByUseAfterExtension"]==null), appBuilder =>
        {
            appBuilder.UseAfterAuthentication();
        });
```

It took staring at it a bit, but I finally understand what it is doing. If the predicate evaluates true for the request, then the runtime sends the appBuilder argument into the function, and my extension method fires. Inside my extension method I create a cookie so that I know it has fired for the request (I expire that cookie in an extension method that runs if the user is **not** authenticated, that code is not shown here). If the predicate evaluates false for the request, then no method call occurs.